# Matlab: I want to display a specific matrix row based on user input

Tags: matlab

My goal is to prompt the user for a value, and then output the row in my matrix that corresponds to the value they enter. The command window recognizes my matrix but does not output the specific rows, even when I enter the right values.

Here's what I have so far.

```
prompt='Please enter an alloy code: '; %enter either A2042,A6061 or A7005 
x=input(prompt);
A2042=a(1, :); A6061=a(2, :); A7005=a(3, :);
%alloy compositions a=[4.4 1.5 0.6 0 0; 0 1 0 0.6 0; 0 1.4 0 0 4.5; 1.6 2.5 0 0 5.6; 0 0.3 0 7 0];
```

So when I enter A2042, I want it to display row 1. For some reason, it's not cooperating. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

An option using [dynamic field references](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/) if you have a lot of alloys and do not want to write out a `case` statement for all of them:

```
a=[4.4 1.5 0.6 0 0; 0 1 0 0.6 0; 0 1.4 0 0 4.5; 1.6 2.5 0 0 5.6; 0 0.3 0 7 0];

alloy.A2042 = a(1, :);
alloy.A6061 = a(2, :);
alloy.A7005 = a(3, :);

prompt = 'Please enter an alloy code: '; % Enter either A2042, A6061 or A7005 
x = input(prompt, 's');

try
    disp(alloy.(x));
catch
    warning(sprintf('Alloy selection, %s, not found.\n', x));
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend against creating separate variables for each alloy name, i.e. don't do this line:

```
A2042=a(1, :); A6061=a(2, :); A7005=a(3, :);
```

Rather keep a variable of names such as:

```
alloyNames = {'A2042';
              'A6061';
              'A7005';
              ...}; %// note this must have the same number of rows as matrix a does
```

Now the row of a given name in `alloyNames` matches the correct row in `a`:

```
a=[4.4   1.5   0.6   0     0; 
   0     1     0     0.6   0; 
   0     1.4   0     0     4.5; 
   1.6   2.5   0     0     5.6; 
   0     0.3   0     7     0];
```

Now when you ask for the input:

```
x=input(prompt)
```

You can use [`strcmp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) to find the right row:

```
idx = strcmp(alloyNames, x);
```

and then you can display the correct row using that index:

```
a(idx,:)
```

Comment: I was just typing this up. Good job avoiding dynamic naming!

Answer (score 1):

Using `switch`:

```
a=[4.4 1.5 0.6 0 0; 0 1 0 0.6 0; 0 1.4 0 0 4.5; 1.6 2.5 0 0 5.6; 0 0.3 0 7 0];
prompt='Please enter an alloy code: ';
switch input(prompt)
   case 'A2042'
      x = a(1, :);
   case 'A6061'
      x = a(2, :);
   case 'A7005'
      x = a(3, :);
otherwise
    warning('Unexpected option!')
end
disp(x);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to declare the variables before you use them, like this:

```
clear

%alloy compositions 
a=[4.4 1.5 0.6 0 0; ...
    0 1 0 0.6 0; ...
    0 1.4 0 0 4.5; ...
    1.6 2.5 0 0 5.6; ...
    0 0.3 0 7 0];

A2042=a(1, :); 
A6061=a(2, :); 
A7005=a(3, :);

prompt='Please enter an alloy code: '; %enter either A2042,A6061 or A7005 
x=input(prompt)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.